# How to show $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt{b_{n}}- \sqrt{b_{n+1}})$ converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_{n} \ge 0  \hspace{1cm}  \forall  n \in$ $ \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.
and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges and
 $ b_{n}=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_{k} $
 Then we have to prove that$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt{b_{n}}-
\sqrt{b_{n+1}})$ converges.

My try:   $$ b_{n+1} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} a_{k} =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \implies b_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}  a_{k}  -a_{n}$$

$$ \implies b_{n+1}= b_{n}-a_{n}$$
 And this gives, $ b_{n}- b_{n+1}=a_{n}$ which can be further written as,  $$(\sqrt b_{n}+ \sqrt b_{n+1}) (\sqrt b_{n}- \sqrt b_{n+1})= a_{n}$$

$$\implies (\sqrt b_{n}- \sqrt b_{n+1})=  \frac{a_n}{\sqrt b_{n}+\sqrt  b_{n+1}} \leq \frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{b_{n+1}}}$$   as $b_{n}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence, now I want to use comparison test with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{b_{n+1}}}$ to determine the convergence of the series given in the question, but I'm having some problem to do that, I think I can use ratio test on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{b_{n+1}}}$ but I got stuck.
I 'll be grateful if anybody could help me in figuring out how can I proceed further from here.
Any other sugestions or methods leading to the solution are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may write, for $N\geq1$, by telescoping
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} (\sqrt{b_{n}}-
\sqrt{b_{n+1}})&=\sqrt{b_{1}}-\sqrt{b_{N+1}}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k}-\sqrt{\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}a_k}
\end{align}
$$ then, as $N \to \infty$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt{b_{n}}-
\sqrt{b_{n+1}})=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k}
$$
since
$$
\sqrt{b_{N+1}}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}a_k} \to 0.
$$